# Online Backup strategy for family individuals

Tags: backup, software-rec

The majority of my family, including myself, uses [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) and [Syncplicity](http://www.syncplicity.com/) free accounts for our syncing needs. However our backup strategy is pretty non-existent, we all have access (via webDav) to our qnap nas located at home, however we copy files accross when we can remember to do so, terrible I know.

Is there tools like [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com/) or [Spideroak](http://spideroak.com/) that allows each the accomodation of each family members syncing and back-up needs under one main account? I'm not sure how this would work, as each family member would need a seperate sub-account or would I manage each computer's syncing and backup lists from a single account? Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked into http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/windowshomeserver/default.mspx Wakes every machine and backs it up as needed; very functional.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is small enough, why not just use DropBox for backup? It syncs in real time, and all the information is stored online.

Comment: data will be around 10GB per user. I've been reading about GoodSync and it looks like a suitable program for syncing and backing up over various mediums (including webdav ssl).

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want online storage and syncing which is just a *copy* of the data, or backup which involves retention and the ability to go back to a point in time.

Crashplan currently offers unlimited storage on a family account. It's only limited by the privacy aspect - the backup account admin has access to all backed up data, but you can have up to 10 machines in 'one household' backing up 'unlimited' data under the one plan. I haven't used it with more than one user yet, but I strongly suspect you would have separate backup sets per person, and that they would be isolated and run independently.

Having all this backing up on-line, may severely affect your internet connection. [QoS may be useful if you can configure it in your router.](http://blog.paulgeorge.co.uk/2012/06/11/setting-up-qos-on-draytek-2920n-router-using-dscp/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CrashPlan, you can connect to its background service running on a networked machine. Here is more information:

http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/how_to/configure_a_headless_client